# Custom titlebar icons - Vista / Windows7

Tags: c++, windows, titlebar

I'd like to add a custom button to my Window's titlebar.  This doesn't need to work on XP - just Vista and later.  Searching on the net yields lots of results for doing it the WM_NCPAINT way (eg. http://www.catch22.net/tuts/custom-titlebar).  Is there a way to do this using Vista/Windows7 with Aero is enabled?

Thanks for any help,
Dan.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do this, even on Vista/7.  If you don't want to use the WM_NC* method, you can create your window without the WS_CAPTION, WS_SYSMENU, etc. styles, use DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea to make a portion of your client area into the window frame, and then draw the titlebar yourself.  However, this isn't less work than using the MC_NC* method because you will need to implement all of the titlebar features (system menu, close box, maximize box, etc.) yourself.